# Django how to see the cookies being set and unset?

Tags: django, cookies

I'm using `response.set_cookie()` to set cookies and `response_delete_cookie()` to delete it.

I'd like to see if things are working as intended, but I don't know where to look for the cookies being set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your views do this.

```
...
request.COOKIES.get('cookie_name', None)
...
```

To get the cookie or `None`.

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to see if things are working as intended

Sounds like the perfect time to add some tests! Here's something to get you started:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django import shortcuts


class TestCookies(TestCase):

    def test_cookie_added(self):
        url = shortcuts.reverse('your-view')
        response = self.client.get(url)
        self.assertEqual(response.cookies.get('cookie_name'), 'expected')

    def test_cookie_removed(self):
        url = shortcuts.reverse('your-cookie-deleting-view')
        response = self.client.get(url)
        self.assertIsNone(response.cookies.get('cookie_name'))
```